# Continuous hover in JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to apply a specific animations using the animate.css framework and hover handler using the JQuery. The effect is applied only once a time but I want to be repeated every time the onmouseover and onmouseout executed. The code I used:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    

             $(".meal-photo-Sport").hover(function()
            {
                  $('.meal-photo-Sport a').addClass('animated fadeInUp');

             }, function(){
                 $('.meal-photo-Sport a').addClass('animated fadeOutDown');
             })
})
```

Comment: you need to remove also the other class ... so on hover remove fadeOutDown and on mouseout remove fadeInUp.... But it's better if you can include all your relevant code here like the CSS and HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the classnames:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    

         $(".meal-photo-Sport").hover(function(){
              $('.meal-photo-Sport a')
                  .addClass('animated fadeInUp')
                  .removeClass('fadeOutDown');

         }, function(){
             $('.meal-photo-Sport a')
                 .addClass('animated fadeOutDown')
                 .removeClass('fadeInUp');
         })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $(".meal-photo-Sport").on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            $(".meal-photo-Sport a").removeClass("animated fadeOutDown").addClass('animated fadeInUp');
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $(".meal-photo-Sport a").removeClass("animated fadeInUp").addClass('animated fadeOutDown');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I agree it could do. Since OP has not specified any HTML, we do not know  of any other classes

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {    

         $(".meal-photo-Sport").hover(function()
        {
              $('.meal-photo-Sport a').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
              $('.meal-photo-Sport a').removeClass('fadeOutDown');

         }, function(){
             $('.meal-photo-Sport a').addClass('animated fadeOutDown');
             $('.meal-photo-Sport a').removeClass('fadeInUp');
         })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use a jQuery extension function provided by Animate Css. Here's how you would do it:

```js
$.fn.extend({
    animateCss: function(animationName) {
      var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
      $(this).addClass('animated ' + animationName).one(animationEnd, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('animated ' + animationName);
      });
    }
  });

  $(".meal-photo-Sport").hover(function() {
    $('.meal-photo-Sport a').animateCss('fadeInUp');
  }, function() {
    $('.meal-photo-Sport a').animateCss('fadeOutDown');
  })
```

```css
.meal-photo-Sport {
  padding: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: tomato;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 4em;
}

.meal-photo-Sport a {
  opacity: 0;
}

.meal-photo-Sport:hover a {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="meal-photo-Sport">
  <a> Demo Meal</a>
</div>
```